# Implicit conversion from "Position" to "UV map"

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

Could Someone **PLEASE** help me to understand this concept? I apologize for posting my question multiple times on this and other forums, but I’m still having trouble understanding it. I have read all the references and watched many tutorials, but I’m still having trouble understanding this concept. I’m a graphic designer.

[image]

1. When we store the position of an object in ‘test’, does Blender still recognize it as a position?
2. When we pass the stored attribute named ‘test’ to the Attribute node in Blender, does Blender still recognize it as position data?
3. When we pass the "test" to the ‘checkered texture’ in Blender, does it perform an implicit conversion to UV maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that there are different data types in Blender, like float, vector, integer and so on.
Second you have to understand that Blender converts these types automatically "inside" as Blender needs it.
As you can imagine it is not very hard for Blender e.g. to convert vector to a color (without alpha) because both are just 3 float values. So x will become R, y will become G and z will become B (xyz -> RGB). (more info:https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/parts.html)
Blender "knows" each data type, so it knows also the data type of all attributes (and you have to tell Blender which data type you wanna store).
So you do store a vector (attribute) to all points in your geometry by "store named attribute"-node. For Blender - it is just a vector. Not a position. You can now "use" this vector as color (if you want to) but also as position or uv coordinate. You decide what to do with that vector. And by using/reading it via shader nodes in attribute and plugging it into the checker vector, you "decide" to use the vector as position. If you plug that same vector into color1, you "decide" to use the vector as color.

For Blender it is still and will always be just a vector (3 float values in an array). Nothing else. You decide how to use that.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you Chris ❤️❤️ This is exactly what I was looking for. I was just reading the ‘Node Parts’ section that you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome